# 2 Dimensional Linked List Array

Tags: java

I am trying to have 2D Linked List Array as:

```
private LinkedList<Integer>[] adjLst;

graph(int n){
    noOfNodes = n-1;

    for(int i=0;i<=noOfNodes;i++){
        adjLst[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }
}
```

But when i am calling it from my main class as:

```
graph g =new graph(13);
```

It is throwing an NullPointerException?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've never initialized `adjLst`, so it still has its default value of `null`. You need something like:

```
adjLst = new LinkedList<Integer>[noOfNodes + 1];
for (int i = 0; i <= noOfNodes; i++) {
    adjLst[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
}
```

It's not clear why you're subtracting 1 from `n` and then going up to and including that value, mind you. I'd find this easier to understand:

```
// Note: fixed case of class. Please follow Java naming conventions
Graph(int n){
    adjLst = new LinkedList<Integer>[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        adjLst[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }
}
```